# Ionic 2 HTTP.post not send data

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I has a problem, When I post data to my api server.

My api server didn't get any data, It send from ionic app.

This is my api providers.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP } from 'ionic-native';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class APIProvider {

  constructor() {}

  getProduct(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

      let body = {
        "data_1": "1234567890123",
        "data_2": "125615"
      }

      HTTP.post('https://ex.com/api/somethig', JSON.stringify(body), header)
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.status);
        console.log(data.data); // data received by server
        console.log(data.headers);
        resolve(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error); // error message as string
        console.log(error.headers);
        resolve(error);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

In api server (PHP), I try `vardump($_POST);`/ But it return `array(0) {}`

Console log

```
[15:20:15]  console.log: 200 
[15:20:15]  console.log: array(0) { } 
[15:20:15]  console.log: [object Object]
```

System information:

- Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
- ios-deploy version: Not installed
- ios-sim version: Not installed
- OS: macOS Sierra
- Node Version: v6.9.5
- Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhhh, I found the answer.

Just changed `"Content-Type": "application/json"` to `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using '@angular/http'.

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

constructor(public http: Http) {}
let body = { data_1: "1234567890123", data_2: "125615" };

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.http.post('https://ex.com/api/somethig', JSON.stringify(body), {headers: headers})
    .subscribe(res => {
      resolve(res);
    }, (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: It got `console.error: Response with status: 0 for URL: null `